# Read vbaProject.bin for macrosCode in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a .xlsm excel file while reading the macrosCode from the vbaProject.bin file.
I implemented the following snippet:

```
  $filename = 'private://zips/xl/vbaProject.bin';
  $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
  $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
  fclose($handle);
  $spreadsheet->setMacrosCode($contents);
```

This is a workaround because the PhpSpreadsheet library does not support generating excel file with macros. But somehow, when reading the vbaProject.bin file, the format seems incorrect, might be because of the encoding. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SGbK.png

My question is: could I read the vbaProject.bin somehow with the proper format?